# SharePoint Search 2013 status shows degraded

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search, topology

When I ran the Health report from Microsoft, I got the below error. 
SSAComponentState        Error   Servers with SSA Components not 'Active': SPDevServer
                                   [ContentProcessingComponent1]
                                     ServerName: SPDevServer
                                     State: Degraded
                                     Message: Registering

From my topology, I see an exclamation mark for my Content processing component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the memory allocated for Noderunner.exe, it did happen to be when one of the Admins tweaked its default settings.